# Is there a way to read data into R or Python and split it by number of characters?

Tags: python, r, dataframe, text

Say I have a number of fields with their respective length of characters. The first field is the ID with length of 10, the second field is phone number with length 20, and so forth. Can I set the delimiter based on the length?

The data does not have any structure to it so in order to read it I have to find a way to construct the table when I read it in. It's a plain text file. I do, however, have the respective length of characters for each field. I have not done anything like this before so before I spend hours into it I wanted to see if this is even possible.

Comment: In R there is the `read.fwf()` function.  I am sure there is something similar in Python.

Comment: Wow never knew about this. Looks like this might work.

Comment: `pd.read_fwf()` for pandas in python

Comment: In python you can index with strings, e.g. `id_field = message[0:10]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python it should be quite simple indeed

In `pandas` you can use the simple function `read_fwf()`

Given for example something like this

myfile.txt

```
1name1surname1
2name2surname2
```

with columns of size `[1, 5, 8]`
you can read the file in this way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf("myfile.txt", widths=[1, 5, 8])
```

Details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) for this function

If you want to parse the file yourself instead, which is also quite simple:

```
import pandas as pd
# column name + size
meta_data = [('id',1),('name',5),('surname',8)]

def my_parser(line):
    curr_dict = {}
    start=0
    end=0
    for meta in meta_data:
        end = meta[1] + end
        curr_dict[meta[0]] = line[start:end]
        start = end
    return curr_dict
        
   

with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f_o:
    lines = f_o.readlines()
    dicts = []
    for line in lines:
         dicts.append(my_parser(line))

pd.Dataframe(dicts)
```

Answer (score 2):

In python you can just slice the string.

```
msg = "ID12345678PHONE123456789012345BLOB"
_id = msg[:10]
phone = msg[10:30]
blob = msg[30:34]
print(_id, phone, blob)
```

Result

```
ID12345678 PHONE123456789012345 BLOB
```

Option 2: If you open the file in binary mode and get `bytes` strings, you can use the `struct` module to unpack them.

```
import struct

msg = b"ID12345678PHONE123456789012345BLOB"
_id, phone, blob = struct.unpack("10s20s4s", msg)
print(_id, phone, blob)
```